# bash pipe and printing with multiple filter

Tags: bash, pipe

I was wondering if something like this exist:

```
tail -f file1 | grep "hello" > fileHello | grep "bye" > fileBye | grep "etc" > fileEtc
echo b1bla >> file1  
echo b2hello >> file1
echo b3bye >> file1
echo b4hellobye >> file1
echo b5etc >> file1
echo b6byeetc >> file1
```

That will make that result :

file1:

```
b1bla
b2hello
b3bye
b4hellobye
b5etc
b6byeetc
```

fileHello:

```
b2hello
b4hellobye
```

fileBye:

```
b3bye
b4hellobye
b6byeetc
```

fileEtc:

```
b5etc
b6byeetc
```

Thanks!

Comment: Yes.  It's called `awk`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `tee` with process substitution:

```
tail -f file1 | tee >(exec grep "hello" > fileHello) >(exec grep "bye" > fileBye) | grep "etc" > fileEtc
```

Answer (score 1):

This works, but be aware that piping `tail -f` is likely to cause some unexpected buffering issues.

```
tail -f file1 |
 awk '/hello/ { print > "fileHello"}
   /bye/ { print > "fileBye"}
   /etc/ { print > "fileEtc"}'
```

Comment: it's working if i cat file1, but not with tail... i dont want to have to run cat... i want the command to run in background... is it possiible?

Comment: `tail` does not run in the background.  When you say "not with tail", I suspect you mean that the buffering issues are causing it to appear to not work.  You can try using `stdbuf` to tweak the buffering, but only if available.